# SSRS report in Sharepoint with performance point when showing the toolbar contained in a small area

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, performancepoint

I have a sharepoint page, in a website where performance point service is enabled. I am using SSRS to create reports, then create a reference report with the dashboard designer to SSRS. In the SharePoint page, I add a PerformancePoint report webpart, and make its source the reference report made by the dashboard designer.

When showing the report with the toolbar it looks like the following:

[image: The report container is small, so a scroll bar appeared]

The report container is small, so a scroll bar appeared. This snapshot is taken from a SharePoint page.

When removing the toolbar in the dashboard designer, the reports appears in the full area.

How can I make the report container width takes the 100% of the available space?

Please advise,

Answer (score -1):

Check the CSS the toolbar is likely creating a container  for the report that is smaller, you should be able to expand it via CSS.